# iPhone - Store an array of Strings?

Tags: iphone, save

What is the most simple and efficient way of saving an array of strings ?
Store the Array in **DISK**

Comment: What do you mean, exactly? In memory? On disk? How many? Are you programming in Objective-C, C, C++? Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *myMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:100];
int x = 0;
for(x=0; x<100;x++) {
    [myMutableArray insertObject: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"This is NSString number %d!",x+1] atIndex:x];
}

[myMutableArray writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```